# Combining SELECT DISTINCT with UNION DISTINCT in MySQL - any effect?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, union

The following two SQL statements are functionally identical:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM table1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM table2
```

and

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM table1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT a,b,c FROM table2
```

...because "DISTINCT" is applied to the union as a whole, and so is redundant within the individual `SELECT`'s.

(NOTE:  `UNION DISTINCT` is identical to just `UNION` by itself, but I included the `DISTINCT` keyword for clarity)

My question here is, is there a performance difference, or execution-plan difference between the two in MySQL? Or are the `SELECT DISTINCT`s turned into regular `SELECT`'s by the optimizer?

Comment: (I was about to point out that these queries are not functionally identical. But I'm wrong! They are! YLSNED)

Comment: I've no experience reading the output from EXPLAIN.  But also, I want to know the answer in the general case, and not just for some particular tables, which is what EXPLAIN would tell me.

Comment: I just tried `EXPLAIN` on two temporary tables both defined as (a int, b int, cint), and the only difference was that with the `SELECT DISTINCT`s, the output had "Using temporary" in the "Extra" column.  So I guess the answer in this particular case is that it's sorting three times (once for each `SELECT` and once for the `UNION`?  I think?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the execution plans.  However, I would expect that the execution plans are different -- or at least they should be in some circumstances.

The first query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM table1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM table2
```

can readily take advantage of indexes on `table1(a, b, c)` and `table2(a, b, c)` *before* doing the final `UNION`.  This should speed the final union by reducing the size of the data.  The second query doesn't have this advantage.

In fact, the most efficient way to write this query would probably be to have the two indexes and use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM table1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t2.a = t1.a and t2.b = t1.b and t2.c = t1.c)
```

This is almost identical, although it might handle `NULL` values in the second table a bit differently.

Comment: I'm not sure how indexes on the tables would help, unless you just so happen to have an index composed of (or starting with) columns a, b, and c (in any order).  But where I've written `table1` and `table2`, assume there can also be a join or subquery, which won't be indexed like that...

Comment: You can handle `NULL`s the same way in both cases, by just replacing the `=` with `<=>`.

Comment: @Doin . . . This attempts to answer the question you asked, regardless of whether or not that is the question you intended to ask.  Your question is quite clearly about tables and not subqueries.  And yes, the null-safe equality operator fixes the last query.  If you have another question about different queries, you should ask *another* question.  Editing this question would likely invalidate this answer, which is impolite.

Comment: Gordon... If you reread my question, you'll see that the gist of it was "How does MySQL treat redundant `DISTINCT` modifiers in a `UNION`?" rather than "What's the most efficient way of writing this particular query?".  While the answer you provided is a useful and valuable side-note, and does indeed answer the latter question, it doesn't actually explain MySql's behaviour in the general case, which is what I wanted to understand.  The SQL I provided (which happened to use tables) was only intended to illustrate the issue.