# SQL Query to get a single column 'name' with distinct values from two other tables having same column 'name'

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables as cats and dogs with 'id' and 'name' for each pet in both tables. The schema can be understood from below:

```
TABLE 'dogs'
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
TABLE 'cats'
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
```

The question asks to 'Write a query that select all distinct pet.name'

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve the problem?

Comment: display table or using sample code to make it easier for readers

Comment: If dogs and cats are the only ones, you can just select distinct name from both and union them

Comment: research the word "union" in sql eg https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: @Used_By_Already Except that in general w3schools content is terrible.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT name FROM dogs 
UNION 
SELECT name FROM cats
```

Using UNION removes the duplicate rows so using DISTINCT is not necessary here.
If you want to display every pet name not only the distinct ones, you should use UNION ALL instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Pets(
ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Pets
```

Comment: Why not just `union` on exists tables?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a temp table which will hold data from both the tables as mentioned below

```
create Temp table pet
as select name from dogs
union 
select name from cats;
```

Select the distinct names from the temp table

```
select distinct name from pet;
```

Comment: Your named the key(word)s to solution (`UNION` and `select DISTINCT`), good!. You could explain them and please check if [temp table is created like this in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table).

Comment: @hc_dev, do you mean to say the difference between `TEMP` and `TEMPORARY` keyword, both are acceptable

Comment: I did not try to use this *abbrevation*. But good you have written that both will work. Since the asking OP is obviously new to SQL and MySQL it would be good teaching to explain keywords (add links: e.g. to [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html), and avoid shortcut-keywords which could confuse when further researching SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct name from dogs
union
select distinct name from cats
```

Comment: Union by itself will remove every duplicate. Using 'select distinct' is redundant.

Comment: What you say is true  but doing distinct either side can make it quicker if indexes on it, it will never make it worse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142553/combining-select-distinct-with-union-distinct-in-mysql-any-effect

Answer (score -1):

select name from (select name, "dog" as pet from cats
union all 
select name, "cat" as pet from dogs) group by name order by name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @TobySpeight How nicely put your comment! Should be an _auto-expandable template_ on SO for `[exp-code]`.